# How do I make a Discord.js-commando command only usable by people with the user IDs I provide?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js, commando

I want a command to only be used by a few people. I'm currently using Commando's Owner List to give them permission to use the command. I'd rather give them permissions than giving them owner perms.

I'm currently using a system where people listed as bot owners can use the command. I want to give them permission to use the command through their IDs and not through giving them owner perms.

```
hasPermission(msg) {
    return this.client.isOwner(msg.author);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `msg.author` have a snowflake field that you can look up in a configured list of authorized IDs?

Answer (score 0):

This will tell the dispatcher to block the command if the result of the arrow function returns true.

```js
client.dispatcher.addInhibitor(msg => {
  if (msg.member.id != "ID") return false;
  else
  {
   return(msg.reply("You can't use me"))
  }
});
```

You need to add it in main.js